# SQL Temporary Table Issue

Tags: mysql, db2, rdbms, data-science-experience, global-temp-tables

I've created a temporary table `DETAILS` and follow the same syntax of creating and inserting in it. But I have not received any result set However, the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements ran successfully and the Row was also affected in the INSERT statement . But the result set was empty when I ran the last `SELECT` statement to view the record .

```
DROP TABLE DETAILS ;
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE DETAILS AS (
SELECT ins_id , firstname , pages FROM 
INSTRUCTOR)DEFINITION ONLY;

INSERT INTO DETAILS
SELECT ins_id , firstname , pages 
FROM INSTRUCTOR WHERE ins_id = '1';

SELECT * FROM DETAILS ;
```

Comment: *the CREATE ... statements ran successfully* - I don't believe, its text contradicts [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  CREATE TABLE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html). PS. There is NO global temptables in MySQL.

Comment: CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE - exists in oracle - this question may be incorrectly tagged.

Comment: What's in your `INSTRUCTOR` table? What does it return when you run `SELECT ins_id , firstname , pages FROM INSTRUCTOR WHERE ins_id = '1';`? Kindly re-tag your Question to reflect your actual RDBMS.

Comment: INSTRUCTOR is a simple table holding the records of all Instructors having just 5 columns and 10 records > firstname , lastname , pages , books and ins_id(Pk).  .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve rows in CGTT after commit, you have to specify `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS` option of the [CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0053719.html) statement.
`ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` option is in effect otherwise, and such a table is cleared on commit.